# IE Font styles only display correctly until page finishes loading

Tags: css, fonts

Very strange problem on a site I'm working on: http://storyhaus.com/

The fonts I have used on the site (Georgia and Bebas Neue) display correctly while the page is loading, however once the page is fully loaded they fall back to standard sans fonts. It doesn't seem like the FontSquirrel font-face kit is the problem, as Georgia is falling back to Arial for the copy.

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem?

Thanks

EDIT: All browsers are displaying fine except dreaded IE.

Comment: Not on FF5, Windows. Everything's fine here. Which browser do you use? Can it be a malfunctioning Javascript, that sets body's font-family?

Comment: I think you must put your `@font-face` in the same style sheet in which other styles are defined instead of using a separate style sheet.

Comment: @Ahsan That seems to have solved the problem. Do you want to list as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @David John Smith: I have posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `@font-face` in the same style sheet in which other styles are defined instead of using a separate style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put a CSS reset at the start, and view the entirity of your code, because the css must be getting the information from someone to revert back to Arial.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.  None of them showed the issue you describe.  Is it possible it's just a caching issue?  Try clearing your cache, and then shift-reloading the page.

If that doesn't work, try a different browser.  Also, you should provide the browser and OS you are testing on for these sorts of questions.

Comment: You're right, it's displaying correctly in all browsers except dreaded IE. I have updated my question.